# Windows Mobile 6 SDK, cannot print debug logs

Tags: c#, debugging, logging, console, windows-mobile-6

I am currently developping an app for a PDA (a Windows Mobile device).
I must use the Windows Mobile 6 SDK.

I would like to print logs, like any `Console Application`, but when calling :

```
System.Console.Writeline();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();
```

Nothing happens...
The only debug I can do is writing on a file, or displaying info through `MessageBox`es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Mobile 6.x does not support a console.

Using System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(); prints the line to the Debug channel. You might connect with Visual Studio (Debug->Attach to process->Smart Device->Process).

There are some OEM tools to read from the debug channel, but these also just redirect the Debug output to a file.

The only way to have a persistent log is logging to file. See Log4Net for a full featured logging framework.

You might write a logging to a TCP/IP socket and then use a custom tool to read from this socket, if you need real-time watching.